# Get full route path

Tags: c#, controller, routes, asp.net-web-api

I am using Web API 2 and I want to print the full route path to a log file

Example:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/orders")]
public class OrdersController : Controller
{
    [Route("{orderId}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ResponseObject GetOrderByID(int orderId, string search)
    {
    // [MISSING CODE]
    }
}
```

As a result in the [**MISSING CODE**] section
i want to print ***{GET} api/orders/{orderId}*** to a log file.

(for example the results: *api/orders/123 , api/orders/123?search=* are not what i am looking for, I can find them in the request)

The log file will store ***{GET} api/orders/{orderId}***

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself, thanks

```
this.Request.GetRouteData().Route.RouteTemplate
```